# Magento 2.3.3: Translate in javascript with two variables

Tags: javascript, php, magento2

I want to translate the following javascript line in Magento 2.3.3:

`$.mage.__('Please enter between ' + min + ' and ' + max));`

I have tried the following:

`$.mage.__('Please enter between %1 and %2').replace('%1', min, '%2', max));`

But that doesn't work.

The two variables are numeric values and comes from:

`var min = <?php echo $fieldOptions[$option->getTitle()]['min'] ?>;`

`var max = <?php echo $fieldOptions[$option->getTitle()]['max'] ?>;`

My CSV file contains:

`"Please enter between %1 and %2","Vänligen ange mellan %1 och %2"`

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats not how `replace` works. You have to make two `replace` or make a function.

```js
'Please enter between %1 and %2'.replace('%1',min).replace('%2',max);
```

Or a dummy function example:

```js
'Please enter between %1 and %2'.replace(/%1|%2/gi, 
  function(m) {
    return m == '%1' ? min : max;
  }
);
```